# Moving file to another directory or folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

What is the script to move a file from one folder to another just as like as xcopy in jenkins
What is sript to move a file to another folder in jenkins in groovy language

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [File Operations plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/) for this.

```
fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(
  excludes: '',
  flattenFiles: false,
  includes: '/source/location/**',
  targetLocation: "/to/copy/location"
)])
```